# PSEXEC from powershell

Tags: powershell, pstools, scom

I have been struggling getting powershell to run Psexec.  It works fine for single line commands.  but i need to call SCOM to put the server in maintenance mode through Psexec...

```
    $output = .\pstools\PsExec.exe \\scomserver-u $user -p $password -w c:\scom -h "c:\scom\agentmm.exe servertoputinmaintenancemode 4 Automated Maintenance Mode Now +45m"
```

I have tried to put quotes after every sentence but it doenst help..  I get this error

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

The handle is invalid.

Connecting to scomservername...Starting PsExec service on scomservername...C
onnecting with PsExec service on scomservername...Error communicating with PsExec servi
ce on scomservername:

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following function to start a process on a remote server:

```
Function StartRemote {
   param([string] $computer = $(Read-Host "Computername"),
         [string] $cmd = $(Read-Host "Commandline"))

   $remoteProcess = "" | Select-Object ProcessID, ComputerName, `
                         ReturnValue, ReturnMsg, Cmd
   $remoteProcess.ComputerName = $computer
   $remoteProcess.Cmd = $cmd
   $mc = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass `
         "\\$computer\root\cimv2:Win32_Process"
   $result = $mc.create($cmd)
   $remoteProcess.ReturnValue = [int]$result.ReturnValue
   $remoteProcess.ProcessID = $result.ProcessId
   switch($remoteProcess.ReturnValue) {
     0 { $remoteProcess.ReturnMsg = "OK" }
     2 { $remoteProcess.ReturnMsg = "Access denied" }
     3 { $remoteProcess.ReturnMsg = "Insufficient privilege" }
     8 { $remoteProcess.ReturnMsg = "Unknown failure" }
     9 { $remoteProcess.ReturnMsg = "Path not found" }
     21 { $remoteProcess.ReturnMsg = "Invalid parameter" }
   }
   return $remoteProcess
 }
```

It requires the computername and your commandline as a string, be sure to escape additional quotes, and returns a custom object with info about your process:

```
PoSH> StartRemote -computer TEST-VM -cmd "gpupdate /force"

ProcessID    : 6992
ComputerName : TEST-VM
ReturnValue  : 0
ReturnMsg    : OK
Cmd          : gpupdate /force
```

Perhaps you can modify it to allow alternative credentials. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make sure the same command line works fine in cmd.exe. Powershell has slightly different arguments parsing rules for a command line.